# Dynamic partitioning in Hive - downside of using one fixed column for partitioning

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

We are planning to use the dynamic partitioning feature in Hive for one of our projects. I understand that this parameter needs to be setup for this to work:

hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict

In our cluster this is set to strict. We are working on having this changed but in the meanwhile we were planning to do this as a work-around:

```
 - Create a fixed column that will always have the same hard-coded value and use this as the first static column for partitioning
 - Use the columns for dynamic partitioning after this static column
```

This definitely takes away the issue of setting up the above parameter. Hive just needs one static column and is happy to partition dynamically for the other columns

I noticed that, as expected, hive creates a HDFS folder with the static partition and then creates the folder for dynamic partitions under that. Something like this:

```
/baseDir/staticColumn=staticValue/dynamicColumn=dynamicValue1
/baseDir/staticColumn=staticValue/dynamicColumn=dynamicValue2
```

So the solution pushes the the actual data one level down in HDFS, which does not seem to be an issue/concern

The question I have is, is there any downside to this solution? From a performance, reliability point of view?

Comment: Forget about clumsy workarounds. You can set that parameter **dynamically** inside your HQL script, e.g. `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict ; insert into table X partition (PTKEY) select A, B, C, PTKEY from Z ;` *(unless your admin defined explicitly the param as "final" in the config file, but I can't see why he/she would do that)* -- cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case any one is interested. I was actually using spark to load data into Hive and its as easy as adding this line of code to allow data to be inserted using dynamic partitioning

```
// Set hive conf to allow dynamic partitions to be created
sqlContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```